# Can we set mozilla vpn on a router?

Tags: router, vpn

I've been trying to understand how to insert mozilla vpn in a router, asked in their forum without any success (a similar question). I know the VPN IP but am not sure what else would be needed, and presume this is not possible.

As a side node, The protocol they use apparently isn't openVPN but Wireguard (afaik).

Comment: If the router's OEM firmware supports WireGuard, or if OpenWrt supports the router, and you're able to pull the WireGuard credentials, then it may be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we set mozilla vpn on a router?

Short answer, no you cannot.

Longer answer follows.

The way VPN works differs depending on what technology is used. Some VPN servers use an open standard which can be used to use standard clients, such as those build-in to windows itself. Other VPN servers use custom technology and require a VPN client to be used.

Mozilla VPN is the latter. It has a custom build VPN technology and requires their own client in order to create and maintain the connection.

When you ask why a custom client is required if there is already an open standard readily available, a few answers can be given:

1. An open standard can be viewed inside-out and if a vulnerability is found, many servers are instantly affected. By using a closed standard, it is not a guarantee that such vulnerability is also a problem on your VPN tunnel because you also use a client.
2. Installing and maintaining this network is easier. Rather than giving a step-by-step instruction, you install software and done. True, one could write their own client and still use the open standard VPN technology, but given that one often already needs to make tweaks on the open standard server, its not weird to alter more than just a few tweaks.
3. If any client can be used with your service, it is harder to control and stand out. Instead, forcing a user to use your client will also make it so that they remember your service better and thus share their name to friends more easier.
4. By enforcing a client, different subscriptions can be used as well. For example, force up to 3 users simultaneously for the low-teer subscription, up to 6 mid-teer, etc.

And there are more, but you get the point.

In MozillaVPN, they state that their client only works on windows, mac, linux, android and ios, and that up to 5 users are allowed at once.

In order to enforce that, of course they will not allow you to create a VPN tunnel from your router, as that would allow more than 5 users to connect, given that it is seen as just one user.

Comment: "_An open standard can be viewed inside-out and if a vulnerability is found, many servers are instantly affected. By using a closed standard, it is not a guarantee that such vulnerability is also a problem on your VPN tunnel because you also use a client._" How is closed-source VPN software more secure than one that's opensource? If MozillaVPN is built upon Wireguard, an opensource VPN, how does this make sense? Generally speaking, VPN clients are usually more about end-user convenience and less about security _(i.e. how is Mozilla's VPN client more secure than the normal WireGuard client?)_

Comment: @JW0914 I mean that you cannot view the source of MozillaVPN itself and they can adjust the Wireguard code in any way that you cannot see, so a found exploit is not guaranteed to work for MozillaVPN.

Comment: @LPChip: Well, you can – [the client source is on GitHub.](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/mozilla-vpn-client)

Comment: @JW0914: "Built upon" are the key words. It means there's more to it than just the raw WireGuard tunnel – for example, it might be that they've added a registration API (which they did), it might be that they've customized the tunnel setup process (like how TunSafe had their 2FA authentication feature), it might be that the data tunnel protocol is a derivative of WireGuard but not 100% the same (as is the case with CloudFlare's WARP), and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly, if your router allows the necessary software to be installed.

The unofficial [MozWire](https://github.com/NilsIrl/MozWire) tool allows retrieving the WireGuard credentials from Mozilla VPN servers (which appear to be really just Mullvad VPN). After the signup is done, you can use a standard WireGuard client to connect.

Comment: Newer fritz box support wireguard vpn for __incoming__ connections, not sure if vpn for outgoing is even possible...